# Xcode: Enable App Groups without developer account?

Tags: xcode, ios-app-group

Is it possible to enable app groups without being enrolled in a developer program? I need to enable app groups to share data between the iOS app and its today extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope you need to be in a developer program for this